# How to access the Ruby Command line in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ruby, rails

I have Installed Ruby On Rails of version 2.1.3p242 on my system. But I can't findout the ruby command line. I have searched but not found.

I have try to to check through

> **man ruby** : Show some details
>
> **man rail** : "See 'man 7 undocumented' for help when manual pages are not available."

May anybody help me to open the Ruby cmd line.

Comment: What happens when you run `ruby` on a terminal?

Comment: to run ruby, what am I write on terminal ? First time using this.

Comment: Write `ruby` and press enter. Ruby doesn't provide a prompt, so don't be surprised if you get a blank line.

Comment: Only blank line shows with pointer blinking. Nothing else.

Comment: And if you run `irb`?

Comment: "irb(main):001:0> "  shows. Is it correct ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two ways of interactively using ruby on the command line (like running `python` or `nodejs`, for example):

Simply run `ruby`:

```
$ ruby
print "hello world\n"
```

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>. You will see:

```
hello world
```

The easier way is Interactive Ruby (`irb`):

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> print "hello\n"
hello
=> nil
irb(main):002:0>
```

Comment: I have use both the condition & I have got same result too. IT means ruby is fully configured in my system.

Comment: @samzha I am no ruby expert, but I'd say that ruby seems to be working.

Comment: actually I am working on a projects where SCSS file is used to handle the css. So for using SCSS I have to know how to use Ruby on rails. Without Ruby on rails I am unable to work on this. So for ruby command prompt which one is correct.

Comment: @samzha That I cannot say. You should ask on [so].

Comment: But in stack overflow my question is offtopic. My question is that how can I open Ruby Command Line in ubuntu. How to use is the another thing. I want to know how to open.

Comment: `irb` opens a Ruby command line. Use it.

Comment: Are you sure because after `irb` irb(main):001:0> cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/myproject. 
It shows error : 
SyntaxError: (irb):1: unknown regexp options - lapp
 from /home/gwl/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'

Comment: Why would you use `cd` in Ruby?

Comment: to reach myproject folder. This procedure is used in windows for using `grunt` command.

Comment: I think you need to start learning Ruby: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339883/to-change-directory-inside-a-ruby-script

Comment: ok 'll try. I dont have much tym to read about ruby. Thanks @muru

Answer (score 2):

If you want a "Ruby command line" then you want  irb

The command ruby is the non-command-line version. You *can* use that from the command line in several ways(*), but it is not a command line in itself.

As you didn't find irb, I guess you may not know about the command  apropos
The word means "pertinent information about" and typing

```
apropos ruby
```

will list a number of ruby-related things, including irb.

The argument for the command man usually must match the command or whatever exactly, so

```
man rail
```

would not find a manual page, even if there was one, man rails normally would, **but** I believe there is no rails man-page and you have to refer to the Ruby documentation for that.

(*) The usual Unix methods, e.e.:

- As shown in the answer above.
- echo 'print "hello world\n"' | ruby
- ruby < my-ruby-prob.rb
- The 'hereis' and 'shebang (#!) methods

Comment: Thanks @Gordon. It mean that for Ruby command line I have configure the default terminal to Ruby cmd line.

Comment: Please help me in one thing that like normal terminal if I want to goto my htdocs project folder I can go through `> cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/myproject`. Then in Ruby Command line i.e. `irb(main):001:0>` how can I reach my path. Please help @Gordon.

Comment: If you mean you have set your terminal session so that it uses irb instead of bash, that would be very unusual, though may well work OK. Ruby is a programming language rather than a working environment, but if that works for you...   I'm not an authority on Ruby, but I believe you want Dir.chdir("pathname").